# Большой Virtual Memory Size в запущенном процессе

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x

Почему, когда я запускаю новый процесс, используя `subprocess.Popen`, и запрашиваю `psutil.Process.memory_info(pid)`, чтобы получить затраченную на процесс Virtual Memory Size, я получаю > 20 Мегабайт? (в скрипте, который запускается с помощью `Popen`, простое считывание и вывод stdin. Stdin к нему передает "скрипт-родитель")

**main.py**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import sys, psutil, shlex

with Popen(shlex.split('python3 ./test.py'), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT) as proc:

main_stdin = sys.stdin.read()
print('Writting main STDIN stream:', main_stdin)
proc.stdin.write(bytes(main_stdin, 'UTF-8')) # передаем stdin процессу

mem_info = psutil.Process(proc.pid).memory_info()
print('RSS:', mem_info.rss/1048576) # байты в Мегабайты
print('VMS:', mem_info.vms/1048576)

sub_stdout = proc.communicate()[0].decode('UTF-8')
print('Reading sub STDOUT: ', sub_stdout)
```

**test.py**

```
from sys import stdin

print(stdin.read())
```

Ubuntu 14.04, Python 3.4

Comment: в эти 20 мб входит ещё и сам питон. Хочется меньше памяти - используйте си или ассемблер.

Comment: А как определить, сколько памяти сам питон занимает? Запустить через popen пустой скрипт? Просто суть в том, чтобы определить, сколько памяти кушает скрипт, а не сам питон. Потом можно будет просто вычесть. Я верно понимаю?

Comment: да, правильно. Вот только какой смысл измерять, сколько кушает сам скрипт, если без питона он никак не запуститься? Можно сделать самый простой скрипт и посмотреть, сколько он занимает. И считать, что это размер "питона".

Comment: Например, программа создала большой list. Мне нужно отследить именно это, без учёта самого "питона"

Comment: тогда в скрипте нужно в самом начале получать размер занятой памяти.

Comment: В тестовом? А есть другой выход? Просто он может быть создан не мной, такие условия. Решение с рулевым прологом питона не пройдёт, так понимаю - он может использовать оптимизации для разных скриптов

Comment: Все может.
В целом, пока мне придумалось такая идея - запускать скрипт не просто, а притворится отладчиком. Тогда можно будет в произвольные моменты получать статистику по процессу.

Способ второй - писать свой модуль, который можно будет через параметр `-m` цеплять к выполняемому скрипту. Но вот только если запрашивать объем памяти в начале и в конце скрипта, то толку мало будет.

Ещё посмотрите на это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема в том, что запускаться там будут не только питон скрипты, но и другие языки.

Comment: @KoVadim А почему питон вообще использует Virtual Memory, ведь он не достиг предела RAM?

Comment: потому что питон такое же приложение, как и остальные. И живет по тем же правилам. А все приложения уровня пользователя используют виртуальную память. А физическую напрямую адресуют только драйвера, ядро и тем, кому очень-очень нужно.

Comment: Но ведь vm создана только для того, чтобы подменять при перегрузке RAM, разве не так? А если есть место, то зачем использовать VM?

Comment: Создавайте отдельный вопрос. Это в комментариях не расписать. Хотя и ответом долго и нудно:)

Короткий ответ такой - Ваше предположение неверно.

Comment: @KoVadim А можно вкратце: на что она уходит? (Знаю, трудный и , возможно, глупый вопрос:) )

Comment: @KoVadim Из этого (http://serverfault.com/q/138427) ответа следует, что vm - адреса каких-то файлов на диске для быстрого обращения? То есть vm на самом деле не стоит компу ничего, это только адреса к реальным файлам, размер которых в сумме и отдаёт memory_info()?

Comment: смотрите проще - каждое приложение хочет 4 гигабайта памяти (на 32битных системах) и хочет считать, что оно одно, единственное работает. Но память не резиновая, ее на всех не хватит. Операционная система разбивает реальную память на кусочки (страницы). Когда приложению нужна память, ОС привязывает кусочек реальной памяти к "виртуальной памяти процесса".  Если на всех кусочков памяти не хватает, то часть их сбрасывается на диск, а когда вдруг понадобятся - достают назад. Преобразование адреса от виртуального в физический делает процессор, пользуясь специальными таблицами.

Comment: @KoVadim из Вашего ответа следует, что vm и есть память, которую занимает процесс, в то время как по ссылке, которую я кинул выше сказано, что rss является памятью, которую занимает процесс. Так что же такое vm? Vm=ram+swap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ответы из комментариев:

---

в эти 20 мб входит ещё и сам питон. Хочется меньше памяти - используйте си или ассемблер.

> А как определить, сколько памяти сам питон занимает? Запустить через popen пустой скрипт? Просто суть в том, чтобы определить, сколько памяти кушает скрипт, а не сам питон.

да, правильно. Вот только какой смысл измерять, сколько кушает сам скрипт, если без питона он никак не запустится? Можно сделать самый простой скрипт и посмотреть, сколько он занимает. И считать, что это размер "питона".